# Can I have tabs open from url and still use ajax

Tags: jquery, tabs

I need jQuery tabs that will also work with a URL

Example I have a profile page **url.com/profile.php?u=1** on this profile page I have some tabs, friends, comments, about, and these tabs load the appropriate page into them using jquery and ajax.

Now I would like to make it where I could also go to a special URL and it will load the appropriate tab.  like go to **url.com/profile.php?u=1&p=friends** and the profile page would load but the friends tab would be loaded already.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I was completely lost but as I typed this question 1 idea came to mind, I could, in my php page set it to use differnt jquery code depending on the page in the URL.

Is there other ways?

PS) I do not want to use jqueryUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **url.com/profile.php?u=1&p=friends** should render the content of the friends tab and have it initially selected. You can adjust your tabstrip implementation so that it takes into account such markup and don't load its content through ajax.